# Delete query removes same records in any row

Tags: php

In my code, sql query deletes the record in table with same name. For example, I have 2 records with same name mani & mani. This code deletes 2 records.

form Code:

```
<form method="post" action="admin.php">
<h3>Delete a user</h3>
<select name="username">
  <?php
  $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT username FROM users");
  while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>"><?php echo 
  $row['username']; ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete User">
</form>
```

Sql

```
<?php 
include('connect.php');
 if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
   mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' ");
   echo "User was deleted!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please read about **SQL Injections**

Comment: Any issues in my code. Is possible for keeping duplicate values?

Comment: As I think you have issues in your logic. What do you need to do? is the username field is unique? If it is not you should try to get a unique field value for the option's value attribute and pass it with delete query where clause.

Comment: I want to add duplicate usernames also. But delete selected username only. In my table, I have id and username columns only

Comment: Be careful with  duplicate entry values and use unique key when delete operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select unique value such as ID in this case

Try this one:

```
<form method="post" action="admin.php">
<h3>Delete a user</h3>
<select name="username">
  <?php
  $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT username FROM users");
  while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>"><?php echo 
  $row['username']; ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete User">
</form>
```

SQL

```
<?php 
include('connect.php');
 if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
  $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
   mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE user_id = '$user_id' ");
   echo "User was deleted!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code will delete rows with matching names because you have Query :

```
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'
```

To delete specific row you need to use some unique value to refer the row, like primary key!

*Say for example :*

If a user has `EmployeeId`, `CustomerId` or `StudentRollNo`; you could use these options in `where clause`. These tips are very basic things in Query.

Comment: Can you please share the example with primary key?

Comment: I have id and username only in this table. Is that possible to delete one record only?

Comment: If id is not repeating value then definitely you can; like : DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$idValue'